# gdal_contour is missing lines below a certain elevation

Tags: gdal, contour, gdal-contour

I have a very strange problem with `gdal_contour`. I have a very large GeoTif of Europe and would like to generate contour-lines for that region. Everything worked fine when I had lines every 25m but now I wanted to do it again and have lines every 10m.

It runs through without any error, but I am missing lines below 500-600m. Some lines until 500m are present, but many aren't. And below 500m I don't have any lines. I already ran it twice to just to make sure if there was a problem at first run, but second run had the same issues. Is there anything I am doing wrong here? Here's my command that I used.

```
gdal_contour -a height -f PostgreSQL -i 10.0 input "PG:host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=contours"
```

I need to have the output in a Postgres DB cause in a later process I would need to simplify some of the lines. So choosing a shapefile wouln't be an option.

Comment: I just tried to create the contours into a shapefile and got this message: `Failed to write shape object. File size cannot reach 4294967284`

So there is a limit to shapefiles....

But does anybody know if there is a limit to Postgres as well after which `gdal_contour` just doesn't continue?

Comment: Is it just not visualizing some of the lines when you plot it or is the data actually missing? Also, you would probably get drastically increased performance and processing speed if you subset your GeoTif prior to processing and merged everything back together at the end.

Comment: Hello,
thanks a lot for your help.
No, unfortunately it's not a visualisation error. The lines just are not there.

About the sub-geotiff... you mean something like `gdalwarp -te <boundingbox>`?

Do you know if there is a limit of lines `gdal_contour` processes? Or what could be the explanation of my missing lines?

Comment: So, these posts about the algorithm are slightly helpful: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Most-optimal-algorithm-for-contour-correctness-td5034148.html; http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50746/most-optimal-algorithm-for-contour-correctness

Comment: Yea, you can subset w/ gdalwarp, or manually using a gui (qgis or arcgis). But, for the file type you're using, there shouldn't be limits on what can be stored, and if it had run out of memory, it should have thrown an error. Is it possible your data simply cannot support 10 m contours? If you run the tool on a subset of the tiff with values mostly below 500 m, do you get contour lines?

Comment: Well, the strange thing is that in some areas I have lines going from the top of a mountain to the bottom, but then there are many areas where it suddenly stops at around 500-600m. So the data basically should be able to work...
I already did 25m interval contour lines and they worked, it's the 10m lines that don't. At least in some areas...

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a zoomed in image of the raw elevation values side by side with the contour lines in one of your problem area?

Comment: Ha... I think i got it... I just reran `gdal_contour` with the flag "-inodata" active. So it seems as if my GeoTiff has some nodata values somewhere. I'll have to check if I still see missing lines somewhere, but now it already looks really good!

If you want the bounty I set up for this question, just post an answer and I'll be more than happy to give it to you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the missing `-inodata` flag of my `gdal_contour` command